# count items in a row conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to count the number of items in a row that meet a list of criteria and place result in row's errorcnt column.  The actual data has abotu 15 conditions and a hundred columns.  I think this sample should illustrate what I'm after.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyList
(
    Item1   NVARCHAR(100),
    Item2   NVARCHAR(100),
    date1   DATE,
    Date2   date,
    errorcnt int
)

INSERT INTO #MyList
  (
    Item1,
    Item2,
    Date1,
    Date2
  )
VALUES
('Dog','Puppy',   '2020-01-01', '2030-01-01'),
('Cat', 'Kitten', '2020-02-02', '2020-03-03')
```

Sample conditions to count:

```
When Item1 <> Dog, OR 
when Item2 <> puppy, OR 
when Date2>date1
```

Each of those are to be counted so for record #2,

```
Item1 <> Dog = 1
Item2 <> puppy = 1
Date 2 > Date 1 = 1
Total 3 errors.
```

Output for row 2 would be:

```
Cat, Kitten, 2020-02-02, 2020-03-03, 3
```

Novice, can't figure out how to do it best.

Comment: This is called *conditional aggregation* which is often completed with `IIF` or `CASE`.

Comment: This is challenging because this is not how relational data works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `case` expressions:

```
select ml.*,
       ( (case when Item1 <> 'Dog' then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when when Item2 <> 'puppy' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when Date2 > date1 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as total_errors
from #mylist ml;
```